# jUpgrade Extension stuck during the update to Joomla 2.5.8

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I have problem with **jUpgrade** extension of Joomla.I have a website which is built in Joomla 1.5.26 and I want it to be upgrade it to Joomla 2.5.8.I am using **jUpgrade**.When i click on start upgrade it start and download and decompress the content but it stuck in the migration process.This snap show it better what i want to say, see below:

[image]

I have Enable the curl in xampp. And also clear my cache and restarting the server.All thing i have tried wait for it at least 30 minute but nothing happen.Can any one have a suggestion how to solve this. please help.

Comment: What if anything has happenedin your data base? Did you get any new or updated tables?

Comment: Ya i got some new tables in my database

Comment: I think i have had it hang like that before and it has been okay. YOu could  login and go to the database tab on the extensions submenu. Then click fix if it reports any problems.

Comment: I didn't find any database tab in extension manager in joomla 1.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you enable the mootools in plugin manager?

Which browser you are using for this process.PLease use chrome.Because it may happen in other browsers.

Comment: Yes i have enable the mootools plugin and i am using google chrome.

Comment: first you just uninstall the jupgrade then remove the tables  jupgrade_categories,          
jupgrade_menus ,         
jupgrade_modules,
jupgrade_steps

Comment: also remove all the tables created by new joomla

Answer (score 0):

first you uninstall the jupgrade then remove the tables jupgrade_categories,     jupgrade_menus , jupgrade_modules, jupgrade_steps.
Also remove all the tables created by new joomla, then clear the cache and install the jupgrade plugin.
Click on setting button in jupgrade then set

Skip checks - yes,
Enable migration debug - yes,
Enable Mootools version debug - yes

Then start upgrading......

I think this will work...