# Joomla Upgrade, stuck on checking and cleaning

Tags: joomla2.5, upgrade, joomla1.5

i am trying to upgrade joomla from 1.5 to 2.5.2 but it stucks on Checking and cleaning...

i am using google chrome,

My Problem Screen Shot:http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/191/1xkr.png/

i have also tried the solution from here [jUpgrade Extension stuck during the update to Joomla 2.5.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128719/jupgrade-extension-stuck-during-the-update-to-joomla-2-5-8) but didn't worked.

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found very useful information please follow these steps to upgrade joomla.

```
1- CURL must be enabled, which was my originally error. 
2- Go to the administrator panel and set the temp path to /tmp
3- Enable the Gzip 
4- Upload and install. com_jupgrade-2.5.2 file.
```

enjoy!.